# BadRequestException: Resource's path part only allow a-zA-Z0-9._-: or a valid greedy path variable and curly braces at the beginning and the end

Tags: rest, terraform, aws-api-gateway, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to create Rest API using terraform. I am getting an error

```
Error: creating API Gateway Resource: BadRequestException: Resource's path part only allow a-zA-Z0-9._-: or a valid greedy path variable and curly braces at the beginning and the end.
```

when i am running it. I am giving the below path part
path_part   = "/example/{example_id}/sample/{sample_id}"
how can i make this work?

I tried by replacing special characters like slashes ("/") with hyphens ("-") but still getting same error.

Comment: Please read this first: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.